# How to deliver messages of a lower priority only after all the messages of a higher priority have completed delivery?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

How to ensure that messages of priority level 2 are only delivered after all the messages of priority level 1 have been delivered?

I'm sending notifications to my users and there can be multiple notifications that each user qualifies for. These notifications have a priority associated with them and the goal is that a user only receive the highest priority message.

**Objective** - I'd like to deliver all the messages of Priority level 1 before starting to deliver messages of Priority level 2.

**Constraint** - I cannot simultaneously deliver notification messages of different priority levels. I can only simultaneously deliver notification messages of the same priority level.

Ideally I'd like to have

1. A queue to which I dump all the messages of a single priority level. This queue will have multiple consumers which will simultaneously deliver these messages.
2. Once all the messages of a say priority level 1 have been delivered and the queue is empty, I'll dump all messages of priority level 2 into the queue to be simultaneously delivered by multiple consumers
3. Continue the above process for subsequent priority levels

**Question** - I'm wondering how to implement this design/flow in RabbitMQ? Alternatively is there a better approach to handling this situation.

Please let me know if I'm not understandable on something and could add more details to clarify.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ supports [priority queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html). Please read the document carefully, especially the performance implications of having many different priority levels.